# How to manually do Run CMake & Run in QT Creator

Tags: c++, cmake, qt-creator

I'm using QT Creator 3.5.1 on Ubuntu 16.0.4 for a C++ project. 
"Run CMake" and "Run" commands work fine in the IDE.
I want to do these two things from a terminal without the IDE. How can I do this?

Answer (score 3):

Qt creator will actually tell you in the 'compile out' pane what commands are run for cmake, usually along the line of `cmake --build . -- target all`. For running the application you just find the build folder and the executable, alternatively you can peek at the Projects > Run configuration (in case you specify some arguments, but clearly that's not the case)

Comment: That doesn't show you the commands for "run CMake" from the Qt Creator menu though.

Answer (score 1):

Note that with a new cmake (>= 3.7) you want to make sure not to use cmake in the build directory that is seen by Qt Creator while that has the project open. Creator will be running cmake in server-mode and that does not like any of the cmake files being changed:-/

Creator should print exactly what it runs in the output pane. For a build that is `cmake --build . --target all` (in the build directory).

Make sure to run the command in the right directory. For builds that is the top level build directory, while for build targets that can be set in Project mode.

Sometimes you also need some environment variables to be set (to pick up libraries, etc.). Creator does show the environment it uses to build or run things in Project mode.